# Linq To SQL - Getting Empty Brackets

Tags: linq-to-sql

When i view the Linq to SQL value i found thos

```
 [t0].[] AS [Stamp]
```

this should be

```
[t0].[Stamp] AS [Stamp]
```

My Question is why this could happen?

The error i get because of this is:

> An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO
>   statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look
>   for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed.
>   Change the alias to a valid name.

Comment: What does the Linq look like that's generating the SQL? And what's the table definition?

Comment: Thanks Chris Solved it

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone go through this. It all started when i added a column manually to the dbml file.

I missed one property.

I looked again to the Stamp field in dbml and found that i missed to fill the Source Property.

Thanks